# Dropdown values not showing when I click dropdown button - Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Dropdown values not showing in Address section. I used bootstrap 4 code.

I am not getting any error, when I am clicking dropdown it's not showing dropdown values.

I have added bootstrap 4 dropdown on this page but it's not working dropdown.

Please help with this.

Here is the code for review and I am a beginner at the react js. Please help

```
import React from 'react'
    
    const ProfileInfo = () => {
      return (
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <div className="row clearfix">
            <div className="col-md-6 col-sm-12">&nbsp;</div>
            <div className="col-md-6 col-sm-12">&nbsp;</div>
          </div>
          <div className="row clearfix">
            <div className="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <div className="card mb-3 shadow-sm p-3 bg-white rounded" >
                <h5 className="card-title" style={{ color: '#009540' }}><strong>Profile: </strong> </h5>
                <p className="card-text"><strong>Navn: </strong> Bengt Nilsfors</p>
                <p className="card-text"><strong>Kontaktinformasjon: </strong> 95833897, nilsfors@gmail.com</p>
                <div className="dropdown">
      <button className="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Address
      </button>
      <div className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Address1</a>
        <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Address2</a>
      </div>
    </div><br/>
                <p className="card-text"><strong>Adresse: </strong> Nøkken 7 H0101, 9016 Tromsø</p>
                <p className="card-text"><strong>Passord: </strong> ***********</p>
                <button className="btn btn-success">Rediger</button>
                </div>
        </div>
            <div className="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <div className="card mb-3 shadow-sm p-3 bg-white rounded" >
        <h5 className="card-title" style={{ color: '#009540' }} ><strong>Nettverksanalyse</strong></h5>
                <img className="card-img" variant="top" src="../images/testimg.png" style={{ width: '152px' }} />
                <div style= {{ position: 'absolute', top: '66px', right: '108px' }}>17:58:55: Henter nettverskinfo...<br/>
    18:00:31: Nettverkstatus ok. Ingen feil funnet.</div>
            <button className="btn btn-warning mt-2 text-center">See details</button>
              </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-4 mt-5 text-center">
        <div className="card mb-3 shadow-sm p-3 bg-white rounded" >
          <div className="card-body">
            <h5 className="card-title" style={{ color: '#009540' }}>Abonnement</h5>
            <p className="card-text"><strong>Internett</strong></p>
            <p className="card-text">Giga (1000/1000) Kr 699,- per mnd.</p>
            <a href="#" className="btn btn-success">Oppgrader</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        <div className="col-md-4 mt-5 text-center">
        <div className="card mb-3 shadow-sm p-3  bg-white rounded">
          <div className="card-body">
                <h5 className="card-title" style={{ color: '#009540' }}>Faktura</h5>
                <ul className="list-group" style= {{ float: 'left' }}>
                          <li><a className="card-link" href="https://www.homenet.no/" target="_blank" style={{ color: '#009540' }}>Mars 2021</a></li>
                          <li><a className="card-link" href="https://www.homenet.no/" target="_blank" style={{ color: '#009540' }}>Desember 2020</a></li>
                          <li><a className="card-link"href="https://www.homenet.no/" target="_blank" style={{ color: '#009540' }}>Februar 2021</a></li>
    
                </ul><ul className="list-group" style={{ float: 'right' }}>
                       <li><a className="card-link" href="https://www.homenet.no/" target="_blank" style={{ color: '#009540' }}>Desember 2020</a></li>
                          <li><a className="card-link" href="https://www.homenet.no/" target="_blank" style={{ color: '#009540' }}> November 2020</a></li>
                          <li><a className="card-link" href="https://www.homenet.no/" target="_blank" style={{ color: '#009540' }}>Oktober 2020</a></li>
                  </ul>
           <div style={{ marginTop: '76px' }}> <a href="#" className="btn btn-success mt-3">Se alle</a></div>
          </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        <div className="col-md-4 mt-5 text-center">
        <div className="card mb-3 shadow-sm p-3  bg-white rounded">
          <div className="card-body">
            <h5 className="card-title" style={{ color: '#009540' }}>Kontakt oss</h5>
            <p className="card-text">Kontakt oss via chat eller telefon 38 99 01 00.</p>
            <a href="#" className="btn btn-success">Chat</a>
          </div>
        </div>
          </div>
          </div>
          </div>
    
      )
    }
    
    export default ProfileInfo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use an html table. Then your code will look like this :

```
<button className="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Address
      </button>
      <ul className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <li><a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Address1</a></li>
        <li><a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Address2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

But with React you have a specific bootstrap components. You should use these components : https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/

Comment: In my application, they are using only bootstrap not react-bootstrap. that's why I used bootstrap 4 code

Comment: that code also corrects right why it is not working. Please help